# Mac mini M1 died while I was working on it!

Tags: mac, mac-mini

I turned the Mac on this morning and everything was fine, almost an hour into normal work it just turned off - no shutdown - no error - it just died. I changed socket, replaced the power cable, plugged it into another Mac to see if it shows up in the Apple Configurator 2, but nothing.

As soon as the Mac went dark, I instantly placed my hand on it to check the temperature and it was normal. There was no burning smell or anything. I opened it up to check if I can find any visible problems, but nothing.

Can anyone help figure out what could've gone wrong?

Comment: Does the little light at the front still light up if you try to turn it on? If nothing works, take it to an Apple repair shop and hope for the best.

Comment: Without putting hands on, it's impossible to diagnose over this type of venue.  It's important to note that not all failures are due to a component overheating.  A capacitor, resistor, diode, transistor, or even a processor could have failed.  Nobody will know until some hands on diagnostics are preformed.

Comment: @nohillside - The light is dead. Not even a blink since it failed.

Comment: @Allan - You're right, modern boards are highly sophisticated. I guess only a technician can figure out what failed. 12 years of using Macs, never witnessed a hardware failure like this.

Comment: No light on the front would point me in the direction of power delivery - either the power supply or a failure of the power rails up to and including the SMC.  But again, without putting hands on, we can only take broad guesses because it could be a simple transistor that failed that switches power on/off to the whole system rather than a major component in the power supply (like a smoothing capacitor or a transformer).